# Php обрезать ссылку

Tags: preg_match, php

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста, есть ссылка вида

```
http://site.ru/index.php?id=123
http://site.ru/news.php?id=123
http://site.ru/index.php?qwerty=123
```

Так вот, мне нужно получить site.ru, при этом обрезав все параметры, и файлы(index.php, news.php и т.д)

Answer (score 4):

Функция [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) вам поможет.